# angularjs ng-options not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I try to make a simple select dropdown with AngularJS

this is my code:

```
<select class="span3" novalidate=""  data-ng-options="select p.name for p in create_options_array(item.values)">                                                </select>
```

`create_options_array(item.values)` is in this form:

```
[{"id":0,"name":"OG"},{"id":1,"name":"OS"},{"id":2,"name":"PG"},{"id":3,"name":"PS"}]
```

the select dropdown appears but it does not have any value on it to select, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: would be helpful if u can post a fiddle

Comment: correct me if i am wrong, but is `data-ng-options`really the correct way to use the ngOptions directive?

Comment: `data-ng-options` is one of the possible ways to refer to `ngOptions`,  yes. It's called attribute normalising, see http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I believe you are missing an ngModel directive and you are invoking the ng-options directive in an incorrect way.

I made  plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/fMAGnonoM9JvuIKvnOYU?p=preview) where it would work.

Comment: this was bugging me for ages! thanks for the help! it's a shame you *need* an ng-model though, I wasn't/am not ready to know where im going to save the data just yet so had to put a placeholder in :(

Comment: you could use a regular `<select>` and iterate with `ng-repeat` on an `<option>` child, if that really bothers you that much.