# AngularJS Directive - How to refresh template after async data load

Tags: angularjs, templates, angularjs-directive, refresh

I forked and edited a plunker from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14619884/angularjs-passing-object-to-directive)

What I'm trying to do is to get the SELECT element (combo box) to update/populate once the data has loaded, but something is not right.  I retrieve the data, and it is on the scope of the SELECT element, but the template is not refreshing to show the data.   Could someone [have a look](http://plnkr.co/edit/RDBSohO3D9m3QooIFH0K) for me and tell my why the template doesn't refresh?

Thanks very much.

The directive:

```
app.directive('walkmap', function() { 
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    transclude: true,
    scope: { walks: '=walkmap' },
    template: '<select data-ng-options="w.postalCode for w in walks"></select>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs)
    {
      scope.$watch('walks', function (walks) {
                scope.walks = walks;
                console.log('watch triggered');
                console.log(scope.walks);


            });

    }
  };
});
```

The Index.html:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <h1>The Walks Data:</h1>
    <div walkmap="store.walks"></div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Solution:

- You don't need another $watch, `scope: { walks: '=walkmap' }` is already watching.
- When using `ngOptions` you must use `ngModel` too.
- [angularjs ng-options not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18074191/angularjs-ng-options-not-working)
- [Working with select using AngularJS's ng-options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13047923/working-with-ng-options-in-angular)

here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SK7mEFyXhpiGsYPSWao4?p=preview):

```
app.directive('walkmap', function() { 
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    transclude: true,
    scope: { walks: '=walkmap' },
    template: '<select ng-model="selected" data-ng-options="w.postalCode for w in walks"></select>'
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your template. You are yet to define a model which is very important

this should work.

```
<select data-ng-model="w" data-ng-options="w.postalCode for w in walks"></select>
```