# AngularJS - ng-options isn't working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-options

I have the following `data.types`:

```
types: Object
  4: "x"
  5: "c"
  9: "y"
```

And i'm trying this:

```
<select ng-options="key as value for (key, value) in data.types">
```

But can't get the select input populated. How to do this with `ng-options` instead of `ng-repeat`.

Comment: This should work. Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem. Use http://plnkr.co

Comment: You are missing an `ng-model` for that to work - see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18074191/angularjs-ng-options-not-working/18074647#18074647

Comment: @Florian Yeah, right! Thanks!

Comment: No problem! I took the liberty and flagged this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<select ng-model="yourModel" ng-options="key as value for (key, value) in data.types">
```

Should work

Answer (score 1):

You missed `ng-model` in you select tag.

```
<select ng-model="yourNgModel" ng-options="key as value for (key, value) in data.types">
</select>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/414dow6m/